# Only accept local request in ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC app and in one of the controllers, I would like to implement an action that only accepts requests from local (i.e. request originates from 127.0.0.1, or from the same address as the server's IP).

I've been looking for a filter in ASP.Net Core that is suitable for this purpose but can't seem to find one. I can use an AuthorizeAttribute, e.g. `[Authorize(Policy = "LocalOnly")]`

and registering the corresponding policy in ConfigureServices in Startup:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("LocalOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext mvcContext)
            {
                return mvcContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal();
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

where `IsLocal()` is an extension method of `HttpRequest`.

However I don't think this is the right way to do it -- what I'm trying to do is not actually authorization, and since I don't have authentication in my program, the error produced isn't correct either.

Is there a simple and legit way to do what I want with filters? Or is this actually something that should be done in the action logic in controllers? Or perhaps this whole idea of checking for local request isn't very correct to begin with?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it as ASP.NET Core middleware.

In the easiest case with a `app.Use(...)` method.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.Request.IsLocal())
            {
                // Forbidden http status code
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                return;
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });
    }
}
```

The delegate calls return on local requests, stopping the middleware pipeline here.

But I'm not 100% certain what you are trying to archive.

Do you want the service only callable from your internal network? The way easier way to do that would be to use docker containers, add the services which need to communicate to each other to the same network and only expose the application to outside the container which really need to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However middleware would apply to all requests coming to the server. Any way to make it apply only to specific controller/actions?

Comment: You can use any other type of action filters, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) Resource, Exception, Result filters. Or configure the middleware per controller/action or use the middleware in a filter [Using middleware in the filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-middleware-in-the-filter-pipeline)

Comment: Thanks! After some consideration I think this probably shouldn’t be done in the app itself. Might use a proxy to hide the internal api instead. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Nae: nitpicking :P Just change the logic in the if, I don't compile and run code for validation when answering questions ^^

Answer (score 2):

The extension method of `IsLocal()` should look as the following:

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLocal(this HttpRequest req)
    {
        var connection = req.HttpContext.Connection;
        if (connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
        {
            if (connection.LocalIpAddress != null)
            {
                return connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(connection.LocalIpAddress);
            } 
            else 
            {
                return IPAddress.IsLoopback(connection.RemoteIpAddress);
            }
        }

        // for in memory TestServer or when dealing with default connection info
        if (connection.RemoteIpAddress == null && connection.LocalIpAddress == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

To determine whether request is local, we can check if the `RemoteIpAddress` and `LocalIpAddress` on the connection are the same, or, in case the local IP is unknown for some reason, if the `RemoteIpAddress` is a loopback address.

You can read more about it in [strathweb](https://www.strathweb.com/2016/04/request-islocal-in-asp-net-core/) article.

Note that it will not work if `connection.RemoteIpAddress == "::1"`.
If you do want it to work change it to:

`Request.Host.Value.StartsWith(“localhost:”)`

Comment: I have seen this. The problem though is not how to write IsLocal(), but how to use it, i.e. whether I can use a filter to check for local request, or do I have to do it in the controller itself

Comment: You have to do this in the controller.

Comment: I see. It just appears to me that this should be something that's handled in filters. Seems that filters are not designed for this purpose though.

Comment: A middleware is the place for me.